Iterator pattern with Rust
I am trying to implement an iterator pattern in Rust.
I have two iterators: GitIterator and ConventionalCommitIterator.
The ConventionalCommitIterator is a decorator for GitIterator.
I am using boxes and traits to emulate interfaces.
When I try to compile the code, I get the following error:
error: lifetime may not live long enough
--> src/main.rs:99:13
    |
 92 | impl<'repo> ConventionalCommitsRepository<'repo> for ConventionalCommitsRepositoryImpl<'repo> {
    |      ----- lifetime `'repo` defined here
    ...
 99 |             git_iterator,
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^ coercion requires that `'repo` must outlive `'static`

A link to the code:
https://gist.github.com/azat-dev/d466023cdffb49da461bdb5e5ab45938
use std::error::Error;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Commit {
    pub value: i32,
}

pub trait GitRepository<'repo> {
    fn get_desc_iterator(&'repo self) -> Result<Box<dyn CommitIterator + 'repo>, Box<dyn Error>>;
}

pub struct GitRepositoryImpl {
    commits: Vec<Commit>,
}

impl<'repo> GitRepository<'repo> for GitRepositoryImpl {
    fn get_desc_iterator(&'repo self) -> Result<Box<dyn CommitIterator + 'repo>, Box<dyn Error>> {
        return Ok(Box::new(CommitIteratorImpl {
            commits: self.commits.clone(),
            index: 0,
        }));
    }
}

pub trait CommitIterator {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Commit>;
}

pub struct CommitIteratorImpl {
    commits: Vec<Commit>,
    index: usize,
}

impl CommitIterator for CommitIteratorImpl {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Commit> {
        if self.index >= self.commits.len() {
            return None;
        }

        let commit = self.commits[self.index].clone();
        self.index += 1;

        return Some(commit);
    }
}

pub trait ConventionalCommitsRepository<'repo> {
    fn get_desc_iterator(
        &'repo self,
    ) -> Result<Box<dyn ConventionalCommitIterator + 'repo>, Box<dyn Error>>;
}

pub struct ConventionalCommit {
    pub value: i32,
}

pub trait ConventionalCommitIterator {
    fn has_next(&self) -> bool;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<ConventionalCommit>;
}

pub struct ConventionalCommitIteratorImpl {
    git_iterator: Box<dyn CommitIterator>,
}

impl ConventionalCommitIterator for ConventionalCommitIteratorImpl {
    fn has_next(&self) -> bool {
        false
    }

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<ConventionalCommit> {
        let commit = self.git_iterator.next();
        if commit.is_none() {
            return None;
        }

        let commit = commit.unwrap();
        Some(ConventionalCommit { value: commit.value })
    }
}

pub struct ConventionalCommitsRepositoryImpl<'repo> {
    git_repository: Box<dyn GitRepository<'repo>>,
}

impl<'repo> ConventionalCommitsRepositoryImpl<'repo> {
    pub fn new(git_repository: Box<dyn GitRepository<'repo>>) -> Self {
        Self { git_repository }
    }
}

impl<'repo> ConventionalCommitsRepository<'repo> for ConventionalCommitsRepositoryImpl<'repo> {
    fn get_desc_iterator(
        &'repo self,
    ) -> Result<Box<dyn ConventionalCommitIterator + 'repo>, Box<dyn Error>> {
        let git_iterator = self.git_repository.get_desc_iterator()?;

        Ok(Box::new(ConventionalCommitIteratorImpl {
            git_iterator,
        }))
    }
}

fn main() {

    let mut git = GitRepositoryImpl {
        commits: vec![Commit { value: 1 }, Commit { value: 2 }],
    };

    let mut iterator = git.get_desc_iterator().unwrap();

    let commit = iterator.next().unwrap();
    println!("{}", commit.value);

    let commit = iterator.next().unwrap();
    println!("{}", commit.value);

}

I've tried to add lifetimes for my iterators, also to specify a lifetime for boxed values
At the current moment I receive this error
When I try to compile the code, I get the following error:
error: lifetime may not live long enough --> src/main.rs:99:13
   |
92 | impl<'repo> ConventionalCommitsRepository<'repo> for ConventionalCommitsRepositoryImpl<'repo> {
   |      ----- lifetime 'repo defined here ...
99 |             git_iterator,
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^ coercion requires that 'repo must outlive 'static


I may be missing the point but I don't see why you would try to use the 'repo lifetime for everything.
I removed all the 'repo references and it compiles fine:
use std::error::Error;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Commit {
    pub value: i32,
}

pub trait GitRepository {
    fn get_desc_iterator(&self) -> Result<Box<dyn CommitIterator>, Box<dyn Error>>;
}

pub struct GitRepositoryImpl {
    commits: Vec<Commit>,
}

impl GitRepository for GitRepositoryImpl {
    fn get_desc_iterator(&self) -> Result<Box<dyn CommitIterator>, Box<dyn Error>> {
        return Ok(Box::new(CommitIteratorImpl {
            commits: self.commits.clone(),
            index: 0,
        }));
    }
}

pub trait CommitIterator {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Commit>;
}

pub struct CommitIteratorImpl {
    commits: Vec<Commit>,
    index: usize,
}

impl CommitIterator for CommitIteratorImpl {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Commit> {
        if self.index >= self.commits.len() {
            return None;
        }

        let commit = self.commits[self.index].clone();
        self.index += 1;

        return Some(commit);
    }
}

pub trait ConventionalCommitsRepository {
    fn get_desc_iterator(
        &self,
    ) -> Result<Box<dyn ConventionalCommitIterator>, Box<dyn Error>>;
}

pub struct ConventionalCommit {
    pub value: i32,
}

pub trait ConventionalCommitIterator {
    fn has_next(&self) -> bool;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<ConventionalCommit>;
}

pub struct ConventionalCommitIteratorImpl {
    git_iterator: Box<dyn CommitIterator>,
}

impl ConventionalCommitIterator for ConventionalCommitIteratorImpl {
    fn has_next(&self) -> bool {
        false
    }

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<ConventionalCommit> {
        let commit = self.git_iterator.next();
        if commit.is_none() {
            return None;
        }

        let commit = commit.unwrap();
        Some(ConventionalCommit { value: commit.value })
    }
}

pub struct ConventionalCommitsRepositoryImpl {
    git_repository: Box<dyn GitRepository>,
}

impl ConventionalCommitsRepositoryImpl {
    pub fn new(git_repository: Box<dyn GitRepository>) -> Self {
        Self { git_repository }
    }
}

impl ConventionalCommitsRepository for ConventionalCommitsRepositoryImpl {
    fn get_desc_iterator(
        &self,
    ) -> Result<Box<dyn ConventionalCommitIterator>, Box<dyn Error>> {
        let git_iterator = self.git_repository.get_desc_iterator()?;

        Ok(Box::new(ConventionalCommitIteratorImpl {
            git_iterator,
        }))
    }
}

fn main() {

    let git = GitRepositoryImpl {
        commits: vec![Commit { value: 1 }, Commit { value: 2 }],
    };

    let mut iterator = git.get_desc_iterator().unwrap();

    let commit = iterator.next().unwrap();
    println!("{}", commit.value);

    let commit = iterator.next().unwrap();
    println!("{}", commit.value);

}

I could make it work with the 'repo lifetime too, but I can't exactly tell you what was wrong with it, I can only tell you that your structs did not specify the lifetime, so it probably left your trait lifetime ambiguous and to give that error.
use std::error::Error;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct Commit {
    pub value: i32,
}

pub trait GitRepository<'repo> {
    fn get_desc_iterator(&'repo self) -> Result<Box<dyn CommitIterator<'repo>>, Box<dyn Error>>;
}

pub struct GitRepositoryImpl {
    commits: Vec<Commit>,
}

impl<'repo> GitRepository<'repo> for GitRepositoryImpl {
    fn get_desc_iterator(&'repo self) -> Result<Box<dyn CommitIterator<'repo>>, Box<dyn Error>> {
        return Ok(Box::new(CommitIteratorImpl {
            commits: self.commits.clone(),
            index: 0,
        }));
    }
}

pub trait CommitIterator<'repo> {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Commit>;
}

pub struct CommitIteratorImpl {
    commits: Vec<Commit>,
    index: usize,
}

impl<'repo> CommitIterator<'repo> for CommitIteratorImpl {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Commit> {
        if self.index >= self.commits.len() {
            return None;
        }

        let commit = self.commits[self.index].clone();
        self.index += 1;

        return Some(commit);
    }
}

pub trait ConventionalCommitsRepository<'repo> {
    fn get_desc_iterator(
        &'repo self,
    ) -> Result<Box<dyn ConventionalCommitIterator + 'repo>, Box<dyn Error>>;
}

pub struct ConventionalCommit {
    pub value: i32,
}

pub trait ConventionalCommitIterator {
    fn has_next(&self) -> bool;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<ConventionalCommit>;
}

pub struct ConventionalCommitIteratorImpl<'repo> {
    git_iterator: Box<dyn CommitIterator<'repo>>,
}

impl<'repo> ConventionalCommitIterator for ConventionalCommitIteratorImpl<'repo> {
    fn has_next(&self) -> bool {
        false
    }

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<ConventionalCommit> {
        let commit = self.git_iterator.next();
        if commit.is_none() {
            return None;
        }

        let commit = commit.unwrap();
        Some(ConventionalCommit { value: commit.value })
    }
}

pub struct ConventionalCommitsRepositoryImpl<'repo> {
    git_repository: Box<dyn GitRepository<'repo>>,
}

impl<'repo> ConventionalCommitsRepositoryImpl<'repo> {
    pub fn new(git_repository: Box<dyn GitRepository<'repo>>) -> Self {
        Self { git_repository }
    }
}

impl<'repo> ConventionalCommitsRepository<'repo> for ConventionalCommitsRepositoryImpl<'repo> {
    fn get_desc_iterator(
        &'repo self,
    ) -> Result<Box<dyn ConventionalCommitIterator + 'repo>, Box<dyn Error>> {
        let git_iterator = self.git_repository.get_desc_iterator()?;

        Ok(Box::new(ConventionalCommitIteratorImpl {
            git_iterator,
        }))
    }
}

fn main() {

    let git = GitRepositoryImpl {
        commits: vec![Commit { value: 1 }, Commit { value: 2 }],
    };

    let mut iterator = git.get_desc_iterator().unwrap();

    let commit = iterator.next().unwrap();
    println!("{}", commit.value);

    let commit = iterator.next().unwrap();
    println!("{}", commit.value);

}

I hope this helps.

It’s generally not a good idea to emulate features from other languages in Rust. When you create a boxed trait object, you incur two types of overhead:
1.  Pointer indirection via the Box, which stores the value on the heap.
2.  Dynamic dispatch through the vtable to resolve the method call.
so it’s best to avoid it unless absolutely necessary.
Additionally, when you box a type T, you’re moving it to the heap, which means that T cannot have references, because after moving something on heap, rust cannot guarantee that referenced value will outlive the T, so this operation is not allowed in safe rust. As a result, if your iterator implementations contain references to other data, they cannot be boxed, as this would lead violate rust's safety guarantees.
